# Python programming with Eclipse+Pydev code assistant without sources

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I'm using Eclipse+pydev plugin to develop python applications using a proprietary python framework. How can i set up a code assistant in this IDE without having framework sources available? Is there any open source tool so generate a documentation stub from sources files and then make it readable by pydev plugin without the need of having these sorces in my project? Do you have any ideas?
Thank you,

Alessandro

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're developing against it, you should have at least the .pyc/.pyd files, so, just make sure that you add the proper folder containing those to the PYTHONPATH and add the needed entries to the forced builtins (http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html has instructions).

If that's not enough (i.e.: PyDev can't discover the needed info by introspection from a live interpreter), you can create a file to provide "Predefined Completions" to it (again, http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html has instructions for that).